# using Jackson JSON library with Jersey + Jetty

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I implemented a **Jersey** service using embedded **Jetty** + **Jackson**. Though when I try it with a GET resource (that does not consume nor produce JSON) it works, it does NOT with the POST resource. The message on the console reads:

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.delta.model.EnableDisableMessage, genericType=class com.delta.model.EnableDisableMessage
```

The POST resource:

```
@POST
@Path("/enable")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String enablePost(EnableDisableMessage enable) throws InterruptedException {     
    logger.debug("within Proxy POST method..." + enable.toString());        
    return "it worked!";
}
```

The model:

```
package com.delta.model;

public class EnableDisableMessage {

    private String cell;
    private String instruction;


    public EnableDisableMessage(String cell, String instruction) {
        super();
        this.cell = cell;
        this.instruction = instruction;
    }

    public String getCell() {
        return cell;
    }

    public void setCell(String cell) {
        this.cell = cell;
    }

    public String getInstruction() {
        return instruction;
    }

    public void setInstruction(String instruction) {
        this.instruction = instruction;
    }

}
```

I also implemented this configuration class as detailed by Jersey specs:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {        
        packages("com.delta.model;com.delta.rest");
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
//      property(CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);      
    }
}
```

pom.xml's dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You need a no-arg constructor in `EnableDisableMessage`. But that is not the current issue. That will be the next issue once you fix the current issue :-). I am not sure why you would get this exception if you register the JacksonFeature. I'm curious to see how you build the server. Are you sure that the `MyApplication` is even being used? Can you share the code where you create the server/application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe including the Jackson JSON-provider in your dependencies does help?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `jersey-media-json-jackson` already pulls the above dependency in. It uses it under the hood.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I overlooked that, sorry

Comment: **Hi Lars**,  the dependency you mention above was actually what I needed as well as **peeskillet**'s no-arg constructor

Comment: **Hi peeskillet**, thanks for your comment on the **missing no-arg constructor** ! as you said it was the next error... Regarding your comment on **jersey-media-json-jackson** pulls the above dependency in under the hood, it seems that applies when using Jackson 2.x, that is com.fasterxml.jackson.

Comment: Hi ekremer, thank you for accepting my answer! Glad I could help!